# Dynamic component on Deno Fresh island: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: carousel, lazy-loading, deno, freshjs

I am starting a [Fresh](https://fresh.deno.dev/) website, and I need a carousel component. For that, I choose the [flicking lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@egjs/preact-flicking/v/4.11.0?activeTab=readme). I'm trying to render a Flicking component, but the build breaks:

```bash
➜  example git:(main) ✗ deno task start

Task start deno run -A --watch=static/,routes/ dev.ts
Watcher Process started.
The manifest has been generated for 5 routes and 1 islands.
error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at https://esm.sh/v132/@egjs/preact-flicking@4.11.0/denonext/preact-flicking.mjs:2:56465
Watcher Process failed. Restarting on file change...
```

The current code:

```
// islands/Carousel.tsx
import Flicking from "https://esm.sh/@egjs/preact-flicking@4.11.0";

export const Carousel = () => <Flicking />;
```

**Previous tries**

I tried to check for `typeof window !== 'undefined'` before rendering the `Flicking` component, but it didn't work.

I also tried to use lazy imports:

```
import { lazy, Suspense } from "preact/compat";

const Flicking = lazy(() =>
  import("https://esm.sh/@egjs/preact-flicking@4.11.0")
);

export const Carousel = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={<p>Carregando...</p>}>
    <Flicking />
  </Suspense>
);
```

But the initial result is a `[object Promise]` on the screen, and when I restart the page, the `ReferenceError: document is not defined`  comeback.

Comment: "I tried to check for `typeof window !== 'undefined` before rendering" -- Did you try checking instead for `document`? I believe Deno does provide `window` server-side.

Comment: @rschristian Yes I did =/ The `run` process breaks with the same error: `error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [checking the `IS_BROWSER` constant like in this example](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/concepts/islands#rendering-islands-on-client-only) so the carousel isn't attempted to be rendered on the server.

With that guard in place you could use the same fallback as your `Suspense` tag while the client side is loading.

Comment: It worked! Adding a IS_BROWSER guard along with the lazy loading solved it. The same result if I check for valid document instead of IS_BROWSER. Thank you!